# Setting up youtube-dl on the server to retrieve just the download link

Tags: php, python, youtube-dl

So I'm having problems setting up youtube-dl on my server.
Here's the PHP script that calls YoutubeDL.py.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$command = "usr/bin/python youtube-dl/YoutubeDL.py --get-url  " . "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4kgeyM7j6Y";

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$command = escapeshellcmd($command);
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

I've set YoutubeDL.py privileges to 777, however I'm not getting any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[youtube-dl/YoutubeDL.py](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py) is an internal file with the main class. It is not sufficient to run. Instead, properly install youtube-dl, using one of the following options:

[**install system-wide**](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#installation), for example with `sudo pip install youtube-dl`. Afterwards, the command to run youtube-dl will be simply `youtube-dl`.

Install and run it **somewhere else**, for example with

```
curl https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -o ./youtube-dl
chmod a+rx ./youtube-dl
```

The command is `./youtube-dl`, or, if you leave out the second line, `python ./youtube-dl`.

If you want to modify the source, **follow the [developer instructions](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#developer-instructions)**. Either download [the tarball](https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.tar.gz) and unpack it, or use git:

```
git clone https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl.git
youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__main__.py  # run youtube-dl
```

Run by executing `youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__main__.py`, `python -m youtube_dl` when `./youtube-dl` is in your Python PATH, or `python youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__main__.py`.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed tutorial :) It turns out that my hosting provider doesn't allow installing additional packages, and some PHP functions such as exec() and system() are blacklisted. Is there any way to run Python script in cgi-bin folder with arguments?